# How to implement a SQL query with bind parameter in an r function

Tags: sql, r, oracle, rscript

When using this sql query, it takes quite a while to retrieve the information from the oracle database. I use the query in different skripts, but it is always the same pattern, so I was wondering, if it is possible to put it into an function

```
chunk_size <- 1000L 
passes <- length(ticker_selected) %/% chunk_size  
remaining <- length(ticker_selected) %% chunk_size
temp <- vector("list", length = passes + (remaining != 0)) 
start <- 1L

for(i in seq_len(passes)) {
  current <- ticker_selected[start:(start + chunk_size - 1L)]
  current <- toString(sprintf("'%s'", current))
  start <- start + chunk_size
  temp[i] <- current
}
if(remaining != 0) {
  current <- ticker_selected[start:length(ticker_selected)]
  current <- toString(sprintf("'%s'", current))
  temp[length(temp)] <- current
}
sql_string <- list()
for(y in 2:length(temp)){
  sql_string[[y]] <- paste("i.BB_CORP_TICKER IN (",temp[y],") or ", sep = "")
}
sql_string <- sql_string[-1]
sql_string <- stri_join_list(sql_string, collapse = "")
sql_string <- noquote(sql_string) 
temp[1] <- noquote(temp[1])
```

Comment: The length of time a query takes to (1) execute, and (2) return data is unrelated to whether the request is made at the top-level of the R interpreter or from within a function. If there is room to improve the query time, then it is typically going to be a discussion between you and the DBAs, touching on any indexes on the table(s) in question. BTW: your subject says "bind parameter" but none of your data here shows [parameter binding](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/) (nor do you show execution of the query), is there something missing?

Comment: You may want to consider (true) parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries); `RODBC` does not (because `RODBCext` has since been removed).